# Permanent solution to slow open/save dialog?

Tags: macos, finder

I've experienced the fairly common slow open and save dialog box issue that seemed to come about with Mavericks and stick right through Yosemite.

The following solution has worked temporarily for me:

1) In Terminal: rm ~/Library/Caches/CloudKit/CloudKitMetadata*;killall cloudd

2) In Activity Monitor: Force Quit cloudd

But the problem always returns. I wanted to share the above temporary solution, but also to see if anyone has come upon a permanent solution yet.

Comment: unfortunately this does nothing to me. NO effect-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe there is a permanent solution, since this problem has been out for far too long with little interest to fix it. I would recommend having that terminal script save as a `.command` stored in your dock that you would click every time you need it. To create a document that can do this for you:

1. Open TextEdit.app
2. Enter the following code into the document:

   `rm ~/Library/Caches/CloudKit/CloudKitMetadata*;killall cloudd`
3. Save to a directory with the name `"[a name that you would like].command"`
4. Open Terminal
5. Type in `chmod a+x` **BUT DO NOT HIT ENTER**
6. Drag in the .command
7. Hit enter

Now you can drag in the command to your dock and click it whenever you need

**EDIT:**

Another idea is to use Automator.

1. Open up Automator
2. Go to the toolbar on the left and drag a execute she'll script
3. Paste the code from above into the action
4. Record a "Watch me Do" (by pressing the red record button in the top right) of:

   - Opening activity monitor
   - Seraching for cloudd
   - Clicking cloudd
   - Clicking quit
   - Selecting quit or force quit

     5. Set that to 1000x and save as an app

Comment: The file “KillCloudd.command” could not be executed because you do not have appropriate access privileges. (Permissions show me as Read + Write)

Comment: Did you chmod a+x?

Comment: Yup. I'll try again.

Comment: Because that error only happens for me when I forget

Comment: If it makes it any easier, move the `.command` to your ~(home) directory and run: `chmod a+x KillCloudd.command`

Comment: Ah, was missing a space after the x, but it still doesn't work because it doesn't actually quit cloudd.

Comment: Or at least, it works when I use terminal to do that command, then force quit cloudd in the activity monitor. It does not work when I just use that command in terminal (or via command)

Comment: That is strange, because it should work the exact same way. Maybe it is being used? I need to look into it, as I have not experienced that problem

Comment: For what it's worth, I also tried this old solution: http://osxdaily.com/2013/11/24/slow-open-save-dialog-problem-mac-os-x/ which did not work either.

Comment: I don't believe clouds is a program like Safari that can 'quit'. The killall command(when run on System Processes like Dock and clouds) just restarts the program. So quoting it in activity monitor will momentarily quit it, but then have it reopen. Try opening a choose file dialog to see if it works

Comment: Interestingly, I can use killall cloudd all I like in Terminal, but once I actually force quit it from the activity monitor then the open / save dialog works nicely and in terminal I get: 
rm ~/Library/Caches/CloudKit/CloudKitMetadata*;killall cloudd
rm: /Users/octavian/Library/Caches/CloudKit/CloudKitMetadata*: No such file or directory
No matching processes belonging to you were found

Comment: Also interesting: When I force quit cloudd fro the activity monitor, it doesn't relaunch right away. It's been at least 15 minutes, and it still hasn't relaunched.

Comment: Ok. My computer must be weird or always using cloudd. Does the select dialog work(speedily) with the .command?

Comment: Ok, now it's finally restarted cloudd so I can test... the .command doesn't seem to affect much of anything. It deletes the files, but does not kill cloudd and does not affect the dialog speed.

Comment: Interesting. And using terminal(without the executable) works fine? You may want to try sudo killall cloudd, but you will need to figure out how to integrate that into your .command. I won't be able to helps for the next 7 hours since I'll be on a plane.

Comment: Using terminal in conjuction with the activity monitor works. Only actually force quitting the process in Activity Monitor helps. Also sudo killall cloudd doesn't seem to quit it.

Comment: No problem. I think I can automate the activity monitor solution for you. I'll add it as another answer.

Comment: does not work for me at all under catalina, reason must be elsewhere, only rebooting fixes the issue but it comes back after a random amount of time (usually days)